# Word to describe someone who is inspired

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word to describe someone who is inspired by lots of things?

Or/and in awe of the world around them...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**poetic** maybe?

> *Poetic is a word that describes your self expression. Being poetic is
>   turning little things that no one would see right away and turning it
>   into a wonderful meaning. To be poetic you must have a feeling of
>   knowledge of things around you, taking things of your dreams and
>   making it your papers reality*. [Urban Dictionary](http://pt.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Poetic)

Answer (score 1):

Good question. English seems more attuned to recognizing multifaceted intellectual curiosity than multifaceted spiritual inspiration.

Darwin was said to have had an *enlarged curiosity*. But that's two words, and not an adjective. *Polymath* describes such a person, but I think there's no adjective *polymathic*.

*Intellectually omnivorous* is common but "spiritually omnivorous" sure isn't.

Native Americans, Pantheists, Deists and William Blake take inspiration from pretty much everything around them. Perhaps there.

You've got me scratching my head, thinking this is a word that needs to be invented. . .

Answer (score 0):

The word **poet** might work in certain contexts:

> **Poet:** One who is especially **gifted in the perception** and expression **of the beautiful** or lyrical.

(American Heritage Dictionary)